# How to get a div which is not a child of document

Tags: html, href

code below

```
var n = document.createElement("div");
Object.defineProperty(n, "id", {
    get: function() {
        window.location.href = homepage
    }
})
```

I want to debug a page on a site, but when developer tools opened,
the code will bring me to homepage.(function get executed in Chrome)

How to get the div, then remove it to avoid jumping

Comment: unclear - please explain exactly what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Open the script in `developer tools > Source` (May be from homepage) & place debugger on the `var n = document.createElement("div")` line.

Now navigate to the page which you want to debug, the debugger will get activated.

Now replace the line (Or override the function `Object.defineProperty(n, "id", ..` ) and move step or disable debugger.

Comment: but when developer tools opened, the code will bring me to homepage, get function activated ,and window.location.href = homepage

Comment: Yes, that's why open developer tools on homepage itself. Is it reloading the page on homepage if developer tools is opened ?

Comment: The only workaround is modifying the `homepage` variable without opening the console. Use `javascript:homepage='#';` enter this in url bar & hit enter. (Don't use search with google option in chrome bar). Now since, the homepage variable is modified, the page won't redirect on opening console.